# gedit not working in ssh session: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed

Tags: xorg, gedit, dbus

when I try using gedit in an SSH Session, I get this:

```
max@amancer:/etc$ gedit SWARM.txt

** (gedit:24616): WARNING **: Befehlszeile »dbus-launch --autolaunch=b3945c581ae43ae601b4b5190000000c --binary-syntax --close-stderr« brach mit von Null verschiedenem Beenden-Status 1 ab: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
Anzeige kann nicht geöffnet werden: 
Führen Sie »gedit --help« aus, um die Liste der verfügbaren Befehlszeilenoptionen zu sehen.
max@amancer:/etc$ sudo bash -c 'echo $DISPLAY'
```

Comment: `gedit` can't find the graphic session. From which kind of prompt (terminal, ssh session, whatever) are you trying to launch it? (BTW, using `LANG=C gedit ...` you should have the error messages in english)

Comment: I'm in an ssh session from my MacBook to my other Laptop running Ubuntu (Elementary OS).

Comment: Please add this information to the question...

Answer (score 1):

`ssh` session *normally* do not forward (i.e., make available) the X11 connection on the other side.

`ssh -X` (or better `ssh -Y`) will enable remote graphical clients to open windows locally.

This does not work:

```
[romano:~] 130 % ssh zzzz
Last login: Sun Feb 22 21:35:08 2015 from XX.YY.ZZ
[romano@zzzz:~] % gedit

(gedit:11225): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

But this will work:

```
[romano:~] 1 % ssh -Y zzzz
Last login: Wed Feb 25 14:51:25 2015 from localhost
[romano@zzzz:~] % gedit
[romano@zzzz:~] % exit
```

Consider however that the connection can be slow --- the X protocol is not efficient over slow networks. And sometime the connection can "linger", waiting for all the graphical connections to die.

You may try to use a terminal mode editor (like `nano`, `vim`, `emacs` or much other) in that case.

Comment: Please look at http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;-)